# Is there an automatic email verification support in meteor accounts-entry package

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

... and if there is not, how would one go about implementing it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Accounts.config](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_config). It has an option called `sendVerificationEmail`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Peppe L-G. This is indeed so and I have set this option to true. The verification email gets sent on registration, but the user is immediately logged in. I want to have the user "inactive" and unable to log in until they confirm their email.

Comment: @babbata, in that case I think you have to use [Accounts.validateLoginAttempt](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt) to check if the user has a validated email address when the user tries to login.